# Drag and drop dynamically created web element using Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, protractor

[enter link description here][1]I want to drag and drop an element...
What I found is on click and holding the element there is creation of new element **(draggable=true)** and old element getting **style: "display = none"**.

So now I want to drag and drop newly created element.

How can I drag the newly created element...

Tried below code

```
 browser.actions().dragAndDrop(source,dest).mouseUp().perform();
```

**HTML code**

```html
<===========Before click and hold==================>

<li _ngcontent-c35="" class="list-group-item pr-0 pt-0 pb-1 sortable-item ng-star-inserted" is-attributelist-attribute="true" attributename="MANUFACTURER"><div _ngcontent-c35="" class="position-relative pr-4 mm-attr-item"><i _ngcontent-c35="" class="position-absolute drag-icon"><mm-icon _ngcontent-c35="" ng-reflect-icon-name="GrabTexture">MANUFACTURER</li>

<==================After click and hold====================>

<li _ngcontent-c35="" class="list-group-item pr-0 pt-0 pb-1 sortable-item ng-star-inserted" is-attributelist-attribute="true" attributename="MANUFACTURER" style="display:none;"><div _ngcontent-c35="" class="position-relative pr-4 mm-attr-item"><i _ngcontent-c35="" class="position-absolute drag-icon"><mm-icon _ngcontent-c35="" ng-reflect-icon-name="GrabTexture">MANUFACTURER</li>

<li _ngcontent-c35="" class="list-group-item pr-0 pt-0 pb-1 sortable-item ng-star-inserted sortable-chosen sortable-ghost" is-attributelist-attribute="true" attributename="MANUFACTURER" draggable="true"><div _ngcontent-c35="" class="position-relative pr-4 mm-attr-item"><i _ngcontent-c35="" class="position-absolute drag-icon"><mm-icon _ngcontent-c35="" ng-reflect-icon-name="GrabTexture">MANUFACTURER</li>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please provide a small example which reproduces the error. Paste relevant html, js and the exact error message which is displayed. It's way more helpful if you paste relevant code into your question instead of just creating a picture. When pasting we can copy and play with it.

Comment: Hi @Silvan Bregy Here I added html snippet.